# Spring JAVAX Validation Year Greater or Equal to Current Year

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am beginner for Spring and JAVAX Validation.

I have DTO class to collect credit card information.

One of the field is `expire year`, is there any annotation or way to validate the year value that it should be equal or greater than current value.

Something as below.

```
public class CreditCardDTO
{
     @Range(min=<currentYear>)
     private Interger expireYear;
}
```

Please guide.

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a [custom constraint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) for this use case.